# How can I make union of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have created a dictionary and filled it with dictionaries by using two `for-each` loops.

```
 y = {'Name': {'User0': 'Alicia', 'User1': 'Lea', 'User2': 'Jan', 'User3': 'Kot', 'User4': 'Jarvis'}, 
      'Password': {'User0': 'kokos', 'User1': 'blbec ', 'User2': 'morous', 'User3': 'mnaumnau', 'User4': 'Trav3_liK'}}
```

Each user has a name and a password. It would be much easier to set my data like this:

```
y = {UserX : ["Name", "Password"], ... }
```

Is there any way I can "unify" my previous code?

Comment: You'd better show your code and what its input is like. Bad output is no use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Answer (score 3):

Supposing User and Password dicts have the same users:

```
y = {
    user_id: (name, y['Password'][user_id])
    for user_id, name in y['Name'].items()
}
```

Comment: to be compliant to user request, build a list not a tuple. But that's the spirit.

Comment: A tuple is the proper type in this case. Jonny, When you have different things, use a tuple instead of a list. A list is for many of the same. In this case, a user name and a user password are semantically different things even though they are both str.

Comment: I agree with that. Tuple is the way if you don't plan to add more items. That should be an edit to your answer, not a comment.

Comment: Yes, tuples are a sort of anonymous record of sorts. Namedtuples are an improvement: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple